# How to test embedded event listener with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

So I have a component that I've built with Typescript, and in that component, I'm embedding a Calendly scheduling page (using [this library](https://github.com/tcampb/react-calendly)). In the component, I also have a continue button that is disabled until the user has scheduled a meeting. The component works as expected, but I'm having trouble testing it, as detailed below.

When a user schedules a meeting (which happens within an iframe), an `EventScheduledEvent` (from `react-calendly`) is fired. That event is heard(?) by an event listener in the component, for which I've included the code below:

```
// track whether calendly event has been scheduled within page
const [scheduled, setScheduled] = useState(false);
useCalendlyEventListener({
  onEventScheduled: (event) => {
    console.log('onboarding meeting scheduled!');
    setScheduled(true);
  },
});
```

Later, I use the state of that `scheduled` variable to set the `disabled` status of my button.

```
<PrimaryActionButton
  data-disabled={scheduled ? undefined : 'disabled'}
  onClick={() => {
    // open user portal
    window.open(Routes.DASHBOARD, '_self');
  }}
>
  Continue to your account
</PrimaryActionButton>
```

Thus, my plan for testing was to fire/dispatch an `EventScheduledEvent` (which I've imported from `react-calendly`) and check that the `disabled` status has changed afterwards. I've tried various combinations of the following, plus a few other things I can't remember, and none of it seems to work:

```
const testEvent = new MessageEvent<EventScheduledEvent>('test', undefined);
document.dispatchEvent(testEvent);
fireEvent( // using jest's event dispatcher
  screen.getByTitle('Calendly Scheduling Page'), // iframe component (have also tried document)
  testEvent
);
```

Am I firing the event incorrectly? Is there a better way/standard practice for doing this sort of testing? I've seen other code in which people have mocked the event listener using `jest` (and passed that in as a parameter to the component), but to me that doesn't feel like it's actually testing anything of value.